Oracle OBIEE Pivot export Excel 2007+ Default to paginate by 300 rows，How do I change the parameter to paginate by 300 rows by default?
Oracle OBIEE Pivot export Excel 2007+ Default to paginate by 300 rows，How do I change the parameter to paginate by 300 rows by default?
export excel2007
excel result：
enter image description here
enter image description here

You may want to change default settings for pivot table in instanceconfig.xml file. There you can increase DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload parameter to match your needs. For example :
<Pivot>
 --other related parameters
 <DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>2000</DefaultRowsDisplayedInDownload>      
</Pivot>

I would recommend first to read Oracle's documentation regarding these configuration :
Configuring OBIEE
You can also try to export data to excel with content paging disabled in your view.
